# creat a newtable with T-SQL using a concated name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to work out a script that will select into a new table from an existing table.   The catch is the table name needs to be a combination of the original table name and a string value representing the datetime.  This is what I have been trying and different variants.  However what I end up with is always a table named newtableName.  Or an error depending on whether I use SELECT * INTO dbo.@newtableName FROM dbo.ClientAppSetting or SELECT * INTO dbo.newtableName FROM dbo.ClientAppSetting.

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE @extension varchar(25)
DECLARE @tableName varchar(100)
DECLARE @newtableName varchar(100)
SET @tableName = 'ClientAppSetting'
SELECT convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 120) AS extension
SELECT CONCAT (@tableName,  @extension )AS newtableName  

SELECT * INTO dbo.newtableName FROM dbo.ClientAppSetting
```

Comment: If you comment out the last command, do you get the expected value for the newTableName?  Also, your last command does not refer to the variable that you created.

Comment: No I get newtableName

Comment: @extension =  SELECT convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 120)

Comment: Based on the code, I would have expected a column header of newtablename and a value of null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL to achieve this. You can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @extension varchar(25)
DECLARE @tableName varchar(100)
DECLARE @newtableName varchar(100)
DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)

SET @tableName = 'ClientAppSetting'

SELECT @extension = replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 120),'-',''),' ',''),':',''),'.','')

SELECT @newtableName = @tableName +'_' + @extension

set @sql = 'select * into ' + @newtableName +  ' from ' + @tableName

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Tip: Although it doesn't look like an issue here, the best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space.